# Socket closed issues

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server and client connection using sockets to transfer files, but if I want to be able to send strings to the server from the client upon user JButton actions, it throws socket closed errors (Because I used dos.close() in the Sender() constructor). The problem is, if I don't use dos.close(), the client program won't run/init the UI frame. What am I doing wrong? I need to be able to send files when the program first runs then send data later.

Sender:

```
public Sender(Socket socket) {

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    files.add(new File(Directory.getDataPath("default.docx")));
    files.add(new File(Directory.getDataPath("database.db")));

    try {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
        dos.writeInt(files.size());
        for (File file : files) {
            dos.writeLong(file.length());
            dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            int theByte = 0;
            while ((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) { 
                bos.write(theByte);
            }
            bis.close();
        }
        dos.close(); // If this is disabled, the program won't work.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Downloader:

```
public static byte[] document;

public Downloader(Socket socket) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        int filesCount = dis.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
            long size = dis.readLong();
            String fileName = dis.readUTF();
            if (fileName.equals("database.db")) {
                List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
                        data.add(line);
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
                parse(data);
            } else if (fileName.equals("default.docx")) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    bos.write(bis.read());
                }
                bos.close();
                document = bos.toByteArray();
            } 
        }
        //dis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first receive loop in the client terminates at EOS, which only happens when you close the socket in the sender, which you don't want to do. You're sending the length ahead of the file in each case so the receiving code should look like this in both cases:

```
long total = 0;
while ((total < size && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, size-total > buffer.length ? buffer.length : (int)(size-total))) > 0)
{
    total += count;
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
out.close();
```

That loop reads exactly `size` bytes from the socket input stream and writes it to the `OutputStream` `out`, whatever `out` happens to be: in the first case, a FileOutputStream, in the second, a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: So I would use this for both the while and for loops I have in the receiver?

Comment: That's what 'in both cases' means, yes.